# De-Versioning [Unity5.2.3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013997/unity-update-method-doesnt-invoke-movement-of-agent) this morning and noticed something.

[unity5.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.2.3)

I've never seen a tag with such an explicit version number (closest I can find would be [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), but its tag wiki makes it very clear to me why it exists).  I was about to just edit it away when I noticed something else.

There are eight other questions tagged [unity5.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.2.3), not a big deal, those can be edited quickly too.  But no, the thing I noticed that completely boggled my mind was that this tag **has a tag wiki.**  It's not useful ("Tag should be used for questions related to version 5.2.3 of the Unity game engine"). The fact that *anyone* thought that this was a decent description of this tag is astounding, much less anyone with the amount of rep required to make tag wiki edits (and they did not--about 3k--so it was reviewed but passed with 100% approval).

5.2.3 didn't even add [anything to the Unity engine worth mentioning](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.2.3). Seriously. Two iOS specific features that barely have 1 line of description in the Unity release notes.  After that, the usual glob of 1-line tweaks and bug fixes.  Not a single image, unlike when [Unity](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0) [adds](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.1) [some](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.2) [ground](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.3) [breaking](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.4.0) [new](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.5.0) [feature](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0).

Can we burninate this thing?

Comment: Unanimously approved in [wiki review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11022891) and [excerpt review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11022892)

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't see that excerpt review. Tag management is a thing that I still mostly consider in the hands of other folks, so I didn't even know how to look for that (or that it exists?). Heck just finding the edit history for the wiki took me a minute.

Comment: How am I supposed to find my 5.6.0-p2 questions if you guys keep removing these tags? So annoying ... but yeah, nuke that thing. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the questions were apparently already edited, and I just removed the tag from the last two. That should get rid of the tag within 24 hours.

There is absolutely nothing about that specific version which warrants it having a unique tag. Just use the generic [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tags. And if there really is something unique about a release, mention it in the question.

There is a wide variety of other Unity related tags which I don't think need to exist, but that's a fight for another day.

Comment: `Just use the generic unity3d and unity5 tags` yep, those are the ones I use/follow.

Comment: I could even accept 5.x tags, because Unity tends to make major changes between those. But the minor and patch releases really don't need their own tags.

Comment: Maybe. I can see a case for (say) unity-4.6 because that's when they introduced the new UI (although it has evolved and grown since; eg. dropdowns weren't added until 5.2) but I doubt any given value of x in 5.x is as significant as python 2.7 (note: I am not a snek-programmer, but the tag wiki makes it sound like a pretty radical difference from both 2.6 and 3.0). But I would keep an open mind for a convincing argument that some feature Y is significant enough to need it, but I'd argue that [unity5]+[feature] would be sufficient

Comment: Agreed, off the top of my head I can't imagine any library needing a tag specific to a minor version. Most (major?) libraries tend to follow semantic versioning these days, even if they don't realise it