# Version numbers in tags

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349318/1997232) question (request to remove [unity5.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.2.3)).

It seems many people misunderstanding (or is it me?) the usage of [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Tags are not the *folders* containing your questions. Tags are *properties* (*attributes*) of your questions.

Consider following example, I am asking a question regarding unity, should I:

1. Tag question with [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and specify the rest as details (sarcasm - in question title).
2. Tag question with [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)[unity5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.3)[unity5.3.3-a5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.3.3-a5)[unity-someotherunityspecificproperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-someotherunityspecificproperty) if I know all this (or someone will edit my question to add those).
3. Tag question with [unity5.3.3-a5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.3.3-a5) only (implicitly add other tags as in previous option? this is probably a feature requiring some sort of ability to link tags as parents/children).

Comment: regarding point 3: hierarchy has always been declined and has never been a design goal for tags, IIRC.

Comment: Is the version *so unique* as to totally change who might be searching for it (to answer, to find answers, etc.)? If not, it's overkill to put it in a tag.

Comment: I have said this several times: on UL we got rid of that tags, volume of questions asked just isn't worth it. BTW, how can you call yourself an expert on 5.3.3 and not on 5.3 or 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [De-Versioning \[Unity5.2.3\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349318/de-versioning-unity5-2-3)

Comment: There are enough discussion and good comments, which have answer on your question in referred question.

Comment: @Rekshino, I wouldn't ask new question if there were enough.. in my opinion all that cleanup around tags is not necessary with properly designed tag system. Though I don't have a ready-made solution and seems nobody is interested to discuss it. Tbh I was asking in hope to get closed it as duplicate, because I am not able to find similar discussion alone.. if it exists.. and it must exists.

Comment: Related (cross-dupe?): [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags)

Comment: @Veve, that's it, thanks. Though I am strongly disagree with Jeff Atwood answer, the topic exist and my question should be deleted (as there is nothing new). Hmm.. despite it's on another site..