# De-Versioning [unity5.3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

We already have a [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag *and* a  [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tag. 5.3 *is* a relatively major version release (unlike the last [Unity 5.2.3 tag I got burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349318/de-versioning-unity5-2-3)) and while it's [release notes are rather extensive](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/08/unity-5-3-all-new-features-and-more-platforms/), none of the [questions with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5.3) seem to have anything to do *with* those new features, except possibly one or two.

I see one about [2D animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155406/2d-animation-is-going-reverse) that might involve the new tools and [one about loading scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170650/unity-5-3-how-to-load-current-level), which had its process changed in 5.3, but after that it's either an error that occurred while the user was using 5.3 or something that could apply to any Unity 5 version, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312233/tiled2unity-pink-prefab-in-unity-5) about importing prefabs with no mention of 5.3 in the actual question...

But...**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** No, no it does not. There are some new features and editor niceties, but all of these can be succinctly dealt with in the question, assuming that it's even relevant. Which for most of the currently tagged questions, does not appear to be the case.

This is not as extreme as [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) which (as a language) exists in a weird state between [python-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2) and [python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3).

Comment: If I can get a modicum of consensus that this is appropriate, I can make the tag go away with the click of a button, merging it into [unity5]. Unless the questions actually need to be cleaned up, in which case manual editing would be more appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, "a modicum of consensus" is what I wanted before doing anything myself (for all of 20 questions, manual removal wouldn't take much). The tag (to me, as a Unity specialist) seems pretty useless, but if there happens to be something that warrants its own tag I'll admit I don't know about it.