# Tag for major Unity versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should/could we create tags for major Unity versions?

It would give additional info about the question and fine-target the use-case.

A bit like how [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) can be distinguished right now.

**Eg:** My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51038377/1524913). I do not know if the issue also applies to other versions (1) but I could also give extra info tagging it [unity-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-2018) or better yet [unity-2018.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-2018.1).

*Note:* I do have the privilege to create the tag myself but, not being sure it'd be as relevant as I'd envision it, I ask for your opinion,.

(1) I'd have to install them, etc. which is a long and complicated process.

Comment: Are there so many differences between each Unity version that warrants a version tag? The example for Python 2.7 vs Python 3 might not apply for Unity as those two python  versions differ a lot (so I'm told). Would it matter for a Unity 2019 user if question was asked for Unity 2018?

Comment: Do know there has been previous version tags for Unity3D: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349318/de-versioning-unity5-2-3 those were not received well.

Comment: Related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags

Comment: I assumed it was because they were specific versions vs major ones. Major ones might have substantial differences but maybe not as breaking as Python2 vs 3.

Comment: There are a big differences- instancing and add listener keeps changes- that this question was downvoted totally clowns Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The transition from Python 2.7 to Python 3 [*intentionally* broke backwards compatibility](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).  In this context, having two different version tags is not only justified, but *necessary* to be sure that the syntax actually makes sense for the application you're running.

**Unless** the major versions of Unity have broken backwards compatibility between themselves, **or** the major versions have introduced significant changes between them which would make using the different versions entirely different (e.g. transitioning code from Java 7 to Java 8 and streams), then my gut says that there's no real *need* for the major version tag.